# How to fix the error 'You cannot add children to a simple form. Maybe you should set the option "compound" to true?' php symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have made a form, but it gets an error message in the form. Here is some code:

```
class ForgotPasswordForm extends FormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new Email(),

            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Code of the createform:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ForgotPasswordForm::class);
```

Comment: Just as a side note, there is already a library for resetting passwords: [*symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle*](https://github.com/SymfonyCasts/reset-password-bundle)

Answer (score 2):

A form should extend `AbstractType` and not `FormType`

```php
class ForgotPasswordForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        …
    }
}
```